# Will rosnode list show the nodes which already died

Tags: ros

Will rosnode list show the nodes which already died? When I refer the node is died, I mean the the process exit for unexpected reason

Comment: The reason why I am asking is because sometime it shows up and sometime it doesn't. When it shows up, there will be an error message like 'Error Failed to communicate to the node'

Answer (score 2):

depends on how Process Died.

Sometimes a Code will exit unexpected and It's Node will become Unresponsive.

when  you call `rosnode list` your node is there but it's unreachable from ROS System. you can call `rosnode cleanup` to remove unresponsive nodes and if your code is running but stuck (which can cause `Error Failed to communicate to the node` as well) you can use `rosnode kill <nodename>` to stop the process.